# Can I manage Ubuntu workstation through Windows like Local or Global Group Policy?

Tags: networking, development, customization

Can I manage Ubuntu workstation through Windows like Local or Global Group Policy? I was told Likewise Enterprise Group Policy could do it, are there any open source solution(s) we could try?

Answer (score 1):

LikeWise is on the repos, is open source.
Besides there are several ways to do such things; but not on the windows method, 
from DHCP scripts to centralized SSH, you can search and try "Migas Free" web app.